# Save Cell Array into 2D-Array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a Cell Array 1*42 .
I want to save this cell array into 311029*42 array size in .mat file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f2Av.png)

How to do it ?

Comment: When I google your question title, [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) is the second hit (after your question). Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cell2mat` function to do this. You can see the mechanism of this function in [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) (see the following image).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just [horizontally concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from the cell array, then [save](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) your new variable like so:

```
newData = [data{:}];
svae('your_file.mat', 'newData');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let C be a cell array of 1x42 size. Then, run the following code to get the output array Y.

```
N = length(C);
L = size(C{1});

Y = size(L(1),L(2)*N);
for n = 1:N
    Y(:,1+(n-1)*L(2):n*L(2)) = C{n};
end
```